# Detect Browser Refresh and Same URL in different tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, tabs

I have a scenario where I want one user to use a particular URL in only one tab of a single browser.

### Conditions

1. User can refresh the page in the same tab, and should work fine.
2. If user opens the same url in another browser or tab in the same browser, there should be an alert, saying you are already logged in.

Can use Javascript / Jquery for the detection.

Thanks.

Comment: Anything else? Make you a sandwich? Mow your lawn? Cup of tea perhaps? Include the code you've tried so far in your question and [show your effort](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I have tried using cookies and window.name but doesn't seem to be working. There is no much code, because its just a condition required for that particular scenario in js.